# Does InputStream.close() do anything?

Tags: java, inputstream

As per the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close%28%29):

> public void close()
>              throws IOException
>
> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.
>
> The close method of InputStream does nothing.

So does it do nothing or something?

Comment: @Saif ... and right underneath it says it doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it doesn't do anything, but `InputStream` is an `abstract` class where `close` isn't abstract (it implements `java.io.Closeable` ), it has an empty body. Implementers of `InputStream` can optionally override the method. `FileInputStream` closes the file input stream and releases any system resources where `ByteInputStream` does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

The `close()` method of `InputStream` does nothing. The `close()` method of subclasses of `InputStream` **may** do something.

Comment: So one should always `close()` an `InputStream`, because it might do something for some, and won't hurt in the general case?

Comment: @arney One should always close all resources, because at worst it'll be a no-op, but at best it'll prevent hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: I would rather say that in general it WILL hurt you if you don't close it. Since Java 1.7 this can be handled automatically with <code><pre>try(InputStream in = new XxxInputStream(...) { } catch(Exception e) {}</pre></code> it the stream implements <code><pre>AutoCloseable</pre></code>which als the provided streams do.

Answer (score -1):

As @Kayaman says, `InputStream` is an abstract class and `close` method is not implemented there. If your are curious you can see this [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/FileInputStream.java#FileInputStream.close%28%29) which sows you close method on `java.io.FileInputStream` of openjdk version 8u40-b25, from GrepCode.

Comment: no the close method is implemented but with an empty body